# Magento Browser Tab Title

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, chrome-browser

I Am developing custom module but cant get solution how to add tab title in browser.

i have added custom_module.xml as bellow

```
<module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/list" name="module_list" template="module/list.phtml" />
        </reference>

</module_index_index>
```

i cant understand how to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the title fetching code in your custom_module.xml file so it will look like below:

```
<module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/list" name="module_list" template="module/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
 <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title">
                <title>Custom Title</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
</module_index_index>
```

**Hope this helps you out**

Answer (score 2):

Add following code inside "<module_index_index>" handler

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="modulename"><title>Your Custom Title</title></action>
</reference>
```